# vulkan x and y switched

Tags: android, android-ndk, vulkan

I am developing a game for android using the android NDK Vulkan APIs. The code is, for the most part, in C++14.  For most cases things work fine, however, on some devices, I have this problem where the x and y coordinates are switched.  I draw on what I think of as the top of the screen, and it draws the objects on the side.  Also, when I do anything with the view point (the view matrix), x and y are reversed.  If I move the view point in the x direction, it actually moves in the y direction.

Also, the width and height reported by the swap chain are reversed.  So that if I plug these values into the perspective matrix like so:

glm::perspective(glm::radians(60.0f), swapchainRetrievedWidth / (float) swapchainRetrievedHeight, 0.1f, 10.0f);

it will draw horribly skewed objects.  But if I reverse the width and height, like so:

glm::perspective(glm::radians(60.0f), swapchainRetrievedHeight / (float) swapchainRetrievedWidth, 0.1f, 10.0f);

The objects look fine.

One device where this happens on is using an Adreno 530, API version 1.0.49, driver version: 35.143.1455, OS: android 8.0, phone vendor: HTC.  For this device, these symptoms only occur if the device is using the split screen mode with the device held in landscape orientation (the app forces portrait mode).  I've seen this happen on other devices too and in the full screen (not split screen) mode.  So, I don't think it is the way I reinitialized the swap chain, pipeline, depth buffer, render pass and command buffers when the screen size changes.  Since the screen would not change size for the devices where this problem occurs in full screen mode.

Am I doing something wrong?  Is there a bug?  I am willing to give more information on this problem, but do not know what is needed.

I tried the same thing in OpenGLES 2.0 on the same device in the same circumstances and these symptoms do not occur. Thanks for all your support and help.

Comment: What is VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR::currentTransform, and what are you setting VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR::preTransform to?

Comment: @JesseHall So, I was setting VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR::preTransform to VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR::currentTransform, but did not notice that VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR::currentTransform was set to VK_SURFACE_TRANSFORM_ROTATE_90_BIT_KHR.  This is obviously what is causing the problem and when I set VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR::preTransform to VK_SURFACE_TRANSFORM_IDENTITY_BIT_KHR, the problem goes away.  So, my next question is: Is this a safe fix for all devices, all modes of operation?  Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Yes, this is safe everywhere. You'll lose a bit of performance and/or power on some devices when the compositor has to rotate your swapchain images for you, which you can avoid by setting preTransform==currentTransform, swapping w/h for 90/270 rotations, and rendering in the rotated orientation.

Comment: @JesseHall Thanks for the info.  If it uses extra power, I'll definitely do the transform myself.

Comment: Ok, I now check VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR::currentTransform, set VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR::currentTransform to this and perform the appropriate transform in my code.  It works fine, but I wanted to test all cases, even for hardware that I don't have.  To do this I set VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR::preTransform to a particular transform and do that transform in my code.  When I set things up to test the mirror transforms like: VK_SURFACE_TRANSFORM_HORIZONTAL_MIRROR_BIT_KHR, the compositor did no transform at all.  Are the mirror transforms just not supported?

Comment: Not all transforms are supported, see VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR::supportedTransforms. On Android, only rotations have been supported so far (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/refs/heads/master/vulkan/libvulkan/swapchain.cpp#41).

Comment: The `supportedTransforms` are unfortunately useless for determining whether you are going to lose performance and/or power on Android (i.e. it tells you what's possible, not what's efficient). The GPU is always available as a fallback for SurfaceFlinger, so `supportedTransforms` is a fixed list irrespective of what the display subsystem can actually handle natively. The only guaranteed way to avoid extra power is unfortunately to ignore `supportedTransforms` completely and just make sure `preTransform` is set to `currentTransform`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Answer based on discussion in comments)

This happens when you set `VkSwapchainCreateInfo::preTransform` to something other than `VK_SURFACE_TRANSFORM_IDENTITY_BIT_KHR`, but don't actually apply that transform during rendering. The safe thing to do is to always use `VK_SURFACE_TRANSFORM_IDENTITY_BIT_KHR`, but if your window is being rotated by the system compositor this is suboptimal from a performance/power point of view.

It's more efficient to look at what transform the system compositor is applying (`VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR::currentTransform`), apply that transform yourself during rendering, and let the compositor know you did so by setting `VkSwapchainCreateInfo::preTransform`.